# Typed Dataset along with Dtos

Tags: wcf, dataset, dto

I have a web application that connects to WCF services for its business logic. I would like to use simple Dto's for transfering data at the WCF boundary for performance and interoperability reasons.

However I have to use typed datasets for data access (ORM or any other option is not available due to political reasons).

Is it a good idea to use Dto's along with typed datasets. Have anyone done this? Is there a recommended pattern? And most importantly is there a library/tool/method to auto generate Dto's from the typed datasets?

Answer (score 2):

Entity translation pattern comes to mind. 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304747.aspx 
Well, maybe a variation on it.

I had to do something similiar recently, and I just created a another "layer" that translates the data stored in the datarow/datatable etc. into the data contract object.  The service layer can call this new layer method with the results from your data-access method as a parameter.

Here's a quick and dirty PSUEDOCODE example:

```
 public class personTranslator
 {

     public static PersonDataContract TranslateToContract(Datarow personDataRow)
    {
        PersonDataContract resultPerson = new Person;
        resultPerson.FirstName = personDataRow["FirstName"];
        resultPerson.LastName = personDataRow["LastName"];
        .
        .
        [etc.]

        return resultPerson;
    }
 }
```

SERVICELAYER Class

```
 public PersonDataContract GetSpecificPerson([Parameters])
 {
     [other setup/validation code...]
    return   PersonTranslator.TranslateToContract(PersonDataAccess.GetPersonRow([Parameters]));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use typed DataRow-s, DataTable-s. There's really not much difference between a typed DataRow and a Dto object.
Performance wise you have to test it that plain Dto-s will help (I doubt it).
As for interoperability, typed DataRow-s are plain classes, so they are as interoperable as Dto objects.

Comment: Well the problem with using DataRows as Dto is they are not marked with DataContracts. They are not even serializable. We have tested the difference between Dtos and serializing datasets and there is a significant performance impact.